# how do I add text around a figure?

Tags: subfloats, two-column, column-width

I have the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{figure text}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{myimage.png}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

myimage.png can be any image.

I am trying to make it so that there is text also on the LEFT of the figure, flowing from the document. meaning, that essentially the figure and its caption appears only on half of the width of the page, rather than capturing the whole width, with lots of white space.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the package `wrapfig`. It allows text wrapping around an image. You can read the documentation. In your example, the image is now on the left side and takes up half the line.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}


\lipsum

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.5\linewidth}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{figure text}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{myimage.png}}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks.